# Object reference not set to instance of an object while getting data from request object/Formcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

i am trying to implement a simple add operation using MVC Ajax

My code is as follows:

```
Public Class Model

{
  public int number1{get;set;}

  public int number2{get;set;}

}


[HttpPost]
public string TestAjax( )
{
  int strnum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Request["txtbox1"].ToString());
  int strnum2 = Convert.ToInt32(Request["txtbox2"].ToString());
  string strnum3 = Convert.ToString(strnum1 + strnum2);
  if (strnum3 != null)
  {
     return strnum3;
  }  
  return string.Empty;   
}
```

It is hitting the Ajax action method. But, i was not able to fetch the values from  the request object or from the form collection

I am  getting , object reference not set to instance of an object error message.

**Updated:** Client Side Code

```
  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestAjax", "Reviewer", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "textEntered" }))
       { %>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="tdCol1Align">
                <label>
                    Number1</label>
            </td>
            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                <input type="text" id="txtbox1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdCol1Align">
                <label>
                    Number2</label>
            </td>
            <td class="tdCol2Align">
                <input type="text" id="txtbox2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id="textEntered"></span>
```

Please help..

Comment: How does your client side code look like?

Comment: You need to **CHECK** whether `Request["txtbox1"]` actually returns a value (and not just `NULL`) before calling `.ToString()` on it.....

Comment: @marc..yes it was returning null.i was not able to get the value entered from textbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `name` attribute in your html element:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox2" name="txtbox2" />
```

Comment: @Dimitiar...thats it..Thank you..Its working now..6 more minutes to accept your answer

Comment: May I know why the downvote ? At least leave a comment. Shesshhhh

Comment: @Avinash I know, it's somebody else, I don't mind, but it would be nice if they leave a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Based on your model:

```
[HttpPost]
public int TestAjax(Model mymodel)
{
  return mymodel.number1 + mymodel.number2;
}
```

And in your HTML assuming you are referencing the model:

```
@model Model
```

replace your inputs with this accordingly:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.number1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.number2)
```

**You have to validate that the user only types integer valid values in your textboxes with javascript.**

Comment: He has a model - Reviewer.

Comment: @higraca..i am strongly binding my view to model by specifying the model name while creating the view. can you give me an example how to create a model from view and pass it to controller method?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the top of the html file (the model include) and the class declaration please.

Comment: @Marcus Ajax.BeginForm() has many overloads, and the one in the example is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505270(v=vs.108).aspx. (action,controller,ajaxoptions)

Comment: @Avinash Can you edit your question and put the top of the html file (the model include) and the class declaration please

Comment: @hjgraca ..Thanks man..This help really means a lot to me :). I imeplemented it straight away